# Ansible Stat function with when condition

Tags: ansible

I have a sub playbook like this.

{{

```
- vars:
    appHome: /opt/app
    aliasName: webbuild

- stat:
    path: "{{ appHome }}/{{ aliasName }}"
  register: folder_stat

- name: Print vars
  debug:
    msg: >
      {{ appHome }}/{{ aliasName }}
      {{ folder_stat }}

- set_fact:
    oldVersion: "{{ folder_stat.stat.lnk_source }}"
  when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == true

- set_fact:
    oldVersion: "{{ appHome }}/{{ aliasName }}"
  when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == false

- name: Print oldVersion
  debug:
    msg: "{{ oldVersion }}"
```

}}

When I run this play book, it return:

```
"TASK [backupService : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /opt/ansible/bullion/ansible/playbooks/roles/backupService/tasks/app01.yml:16
skipping: [STG-app-1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
```

"

Can anyone please help me to explain:

- Is my syntax with {{ `"when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == true" and " folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == false "` }}
- If my syntax is wrong, how's about the right syntax to return the oldVersion like
  {{ `"/opt/app/webbuild"` }}

Thanks you guys so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace 2 tasks by only one task:

```
- set_fact:
    oldVersion: "{{ folder_stat.stat.lnk_source }}"
  when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == true

- set_fact:
    oldVersion: "{{ appHome }}/{{ aliasName }}"
  when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined and folder_stat.stat.islnk == false
```

replaced by:

```
- set_fact:
    oldVersion: "{{ ptrue if folder_stat.stat.islnk else pfalse }}"
  when: folder_stat.stat.islnk is defined
  vars:
    ptrue: "{{ folder_stat.stat.lnk_source }}"
    pfalse: "{{ appHome }}/{{ aliasName }}"
```

Comment: I've changed the code but it still gave failed results like this {skipping: [STG-app-1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

Comment: Btw, I'm running ansible 2.9.7 on CentOs 7

Comment: I've posted the original code below, please help me to check this code.

Comment: it skips the task because folder_stast.stat.islnk doesnt exist, show the content of folder_stat

Comment: TASK [backupService : Print stat] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [STG-app-1] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        }, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "stat": {
            "exists": false
        }
    }
}

Comment: This is the results when I show debug "folder_stat"

Comment: that confirms my comment, your path doesnt exist   see exists:false

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it's so valuable for me.

Comment: glad to help you dont forget to close your question by validating and updating the answer..thanks